# How to synchronise between OpenLdap and Active Directory using java?

Tags: java, active-directory, openldap

My requirement is :

1. all ldap user created in openldap server will be added to the ad server.
2. If password is changed of an existing openldap user then it will also change the password of that user in ad.

I want to know how openLdap can be sync with Active Directory?
Any change in openLdap will directly/using java update in Active Directory.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you having problems? We're here to help, because helping out and solving problems is fun, not do your job for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure OpenLDAP to have an LDAP back-end, and that back-end could be AD. Or there are various ways to configure it as a proxy or member of a cluster such that again AD is another back end. Have a look around the OpenLDAP documentation, it's all in there.